# Not able to get the selected values from multipcklist to my apex class

Tags: visualforce, multi-select

I have VF page where I am displaying 2 pick list I want to move some value from 1st picklist to another.  But when I select and click on add button the value of the selected pick list is empty. It is showing empty. Not able to understand. My code

**Apex class**

```
public class filterScreen_ctrl {

public Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
public String objectName {get; set;}
public String[] FiledName {get; set;}
public String[] selFiledName {get; set;}
public List<Filter_Field_Set__c> FilterField_Lst {get; set;}
public List<String> selectedFieldname_lst {get; set;}
public Map<String, String> selectedFieldname_map {get; set;}
public String selectedFieldname ;

public filterScreen_ctrl (){

    FilterField_Lst = new List<Filter_Field_Set__c>();
    selectedFieldname_lst = new List<String>();
    selectedFieldname_map = new Map<String, String>();
    //selFiledName = new String[]();
    //FiledName = new String[]();
}

public List<selectoption> getorgObjects(){

    List<SelectOption> option = new List<SelectOption>();
    option.add(new SelectOption('--Select--' , '--Select--'));
    for(String objectvalue: schemaMap.keyset()){
        option.add(new SelectOption(objectvalue, schemaMap.get(objectvalue).getDescribe().getLabel()));
    }

    return option;

}

public string RelatedFields(){

    FilterField_Lst = [SELECT Name, Object_Fields_Name__c FROM Filter_Field_Set__c WHERE Name = :objectName];

    for(integer i = 0; i <FilterField_Lst.size(); i++){
        selectedFieldname = string.valueof(FilterField_Lst[i].Object_Fields_Name__c);
        selectedFieldname_lst = selectedFieldname.split(',&,');
    }

    for(integer i=0; selectedFieldname_lst.size() > i; i++){
        selectedFieldname_map.put(selectedFieldname_lst[i], selectedFieldname_lst[i]);
    }   

    system.debug('Selected Field Name map ' + selectedFieldname_map);

    getfilterFields();
    getobjFields();
   return null;
}

public List<selectoption> getobjFields(){

    List<SelectOption> option = new List<SelectOption>();
    Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    for(String sfield: fieldMap.keyset()){
        system.debug('Map contains ' + selectedFieldname_map.containsKey(sfield.trim()));
        system.debug('Select field ' + sfield);

        if(!selectedFieldname_map.containsKey(sfield.trim()))
            option.add(new SelectOption(sfield , fieldMap.get(sfield).getDescribe().getLabel() ));
    }   

    return option;

}

public List<selectoption> getfilterFields(){

    List<SelectOption> option = new List<SelectOption>();
    Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    for(integer i =0; selectedFieldname_lst.size() > i; i++){
        option.add(new SelectOption(selectedFieldname_lst[i] , fieldMap.get(selectedFieldname_lst[i]).getDescribe().getLabel() ));
    }

    return option;

}


public PageReference addFields(){

    system.debug('Selected Field Name ' + FiledName);
    //selectedMlst = getFiledName();
    return null;

}

public PageReference removeFields(){

    return null;    
}
}
```

**VF page**

```
 <apex:page controller="filterScreen_ctrl" sidebar="false">

      <style type="text/css">
        * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        #container {height: 100%; width:100%; font-size: 0;}
        #left, #middle, #right {display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px;}
        #left {width: 20%; padding-left: 2%; }
        #middle {width: 5%; padding-top: 6%;}
        #right {width: 20%; }
      </style>
  <apex:form >  
       <apex:pageBlock >
           <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
               <apex:outputText value="Select Object : "></apex:outputText>
                  <apex:selectList value="{!objectName}" size="1">
                      <apex:selectOptions value="{!orgObjects}"/>
                      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!RelatedFields}"/>
                  </apex:selectList>
           </apex:pageBlockSection> 

           <br/><br/>

           <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!if(objectName != null, true, false)}" id="fieldPanal">   
              <apex:panelBar >
              <apex:panelBarItem label="Related Fields" >

              <div id="container">
                  <div id="left">
                     <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                     <apex:outputText value="Available Fields"></apex:outputText><br/>

                     <apex:selectList value="{!FiledName}" size="6" id="fieldselst" multiselect="true" >
                         <apex:selectOptions value="{!objFields}"/>
                     </apex:selectList>

                  </div>

                  <div id="middle" >
                      <apex:outputText value="ADD"></apex:outputText><br/>
                      <apex:commandButton action="{!addFields}" value=">>"  reRender="middle,fieldselst"  />
                      <br/>
                      <apex:commandButton action="{!removeFields}" value="<<" /><br/>
                      <apex:outputText value="REMOVE"></apex:outputText>

                  </div>

                  <div id="right">
                      <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                      <apex:outputText value="Selected Fields"></apex:outputText><br/>

                      <apex:selectList value="{!FiledName}" size="6" >
                         <apex:selectOptions value="{!filterFields}"/>
                      </apex:selectList>

                  </div>


             </div>
             </apex:panelBarItem>
             </apex:panelBar>
              </apex:outputPanel>       
       </apex:pageBlock>  
  </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Please help me out to get a solution aver this issue. Please guide me where I am wrong.

Comment: you could try by nesting the conditionally rendered output panel "fieldPanel" inside another output panel and change the command button to rerender that

Comment: yes I have tried it before also but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: See if this helps, http://sfdc2u.blogspot.in/2013/05/custom-multi-select-picklist-field-in.html

Comment: Does it work w/o <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!RelatedFields}"/> line?

Comment: yes.. It is working fine for me.